# How to make queue for songs and skip command, discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

I'm tried to make queue of songs few times, but unsuccessfully. I want that when I call first time .play (when the bot do not play nothing) then he starting a song, if I'm calling the .play command second time (when some song is playing) I want that the song will added to the queue and after when first song will end next one in the queue will start. Skip command also need. And maybe someone knows how I can search songs not only by url or key-word, but via both.

music.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl


class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

        self.info = None

        self.music_queue = []

        self.is_playing = False

        self.ffmpeg_options = {
            'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
            'options': '-vn'
        }
        self.ydl_options = {
            'format': 'bestaudio',
            'noplaylist': 'True'
        }

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):
        try:
            if ctx.author.voice is None:
                await ctx.send("Вы не находитесь в голосовом канале !")
            voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            if ctx.voice_client is None:
                await voice_channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
            ctx.voice_client.stop()
            ffmpeg_options = {
                'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
                'options': '-vn'
            }
            ydl_options = {
                'format': 'bestaudio'
            }
            vc = ctx.voice_client

            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_options) as ydl:
                self.info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % url, download=False)['entries'][0]
                url2 = self.info['formats'][0]['url']
                source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **ffmpeg_options)
                vc.play(source)
        except discord.ClientException:
            await ctx.send("Already Playing Song")

    @commands.command()
    async def queue(self, ctx, *, url):
        pass

    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        ctx.voice_client.pause()
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="",
            description="***Приостановлено.***",
            color=0x2f3136
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        ctx.voice_client.resume()
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="",
            description="***Возобновлено.***",
            color=0x2f3136
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Music(client))
```

Answer (score 0):

hey i hope my queue and skip can work i have some other stuff just get rid of the blacklist member part, you also need ffmpeg installed.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from random import choice
import string
from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType
import asyncio
import youtube_dl
import pafy
import datetime
from discord_slash import cog_ext, SlashContext
x = datetime.datetime.now()
from ult import *
class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.song_queue = {}

        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            self.song_queue[guild.id] = []

    async def check_queue(self, ctx):
        if len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id]) > 0:
            ctx.voice_client.stop()
            await self.play_song(ctx, self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id][0])
            self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id].pop(0)

    async def search_song(self, amount, song, get_url=False):
        info = await self.bot.loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({"format" : "bestaudio", "quiet" : True}).extract_info(f"ytsearch{amount}:{song}", download=False, ie_key="YoutubeSearch"))
        if len(info["entries"]) == 0: return None

        return [entry["webpage_url"] for entry in info["entries"]] if get_url else info

    async def play_song(self, ctx, song):
        url = pafy.new(song).getbestaudio().url
        ctx.voice_client.play(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url)), after=lambda error: self.bot.loop.create_task(self.check_queue(ctx)))
        ctx.voice_client.source.volume = 0.5


    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            ctx.voice_client.pause()
            await ctx.send("*Paused -* ⏸️")

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            ctx.voice_client.resume()
            await ctx.send("*Resuming -* ▶️")
    @commands.command()
    @commands.is_owner()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def oskip(self, ctx):
                commandd = "oskip"
                print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
                print(x)
                print(" ")
                await ctx.send("skipping")
                ctx.voice_client.stop()
                await self.check_queue(ctx)
    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            commandd = "join"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            if ctx.author.voice is None:
                return await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel, please connect to the channel you want the bot to join.")

            if ctx.voice_client is not None:
                await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

            await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()

    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            commandd = "leave"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            if ctx.voice_client is not None:
                return await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

            await ctx.send("I am not connected to a voice channel.")

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, song=None):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            commandd = "play"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            if song is None:
                return await ctx.send("You must include a song to play.")

            if ctx.voice_client is None:
                return await ctx.send("I must be in a voice channel to play a song.")

            # handle song where song isn't url
            if not ("youtube.com/watch?" in song or "https://youtu.be/" in song):
                await ctx.send("Searching for song, this may take a few seconds.")

                result = await self.search_song(1, song, get_url=True)

                if result is None:
                    return await ctx.send("Sorry, I could not find the given song, try using my search command.")

                song = result[0]

            if ctx.voice_client.source is not None:
                queue_len = len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id])

                if queue_len < 10:
                    self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id].append(song)
                    return await ctx.send(f"I am currently playing a song, this song has been added to the queue at position: {queue_len+1}.")

                else:
                    return await ctx.send("Sorry, I can only queue up to 10 songs, please wait for the current song to finish.")

            await self.play_song(ctx, song)
            await ctx.send(f"Now playing: {song}")
    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def search(self, ctx, *, song=None):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            commandd = "search"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            if song is None: return await ctx.send("You forgot to include a song to search for.")

            await ctx.send("Searching for song, this may take a few seconds.")

            info = await self.search_song(5, song)

            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Results for '{song}':", description="*You can use these URL's to play an exact song if the one you want isn't the first result.*\n", colour=discord.Color.green())

            amount = 0
            for entry in info["entries"]:
                embed.description += f"[{entry['title']}]({entry['webpage_url']})\n"
                amount += 1

            embed.set_footer(text=f"Displaying the first {amount} results.")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def queue(self, ctx):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else: # display the current guilds queue
            commandd = "queue"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            if len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id]) == 0:
                return await ctx.send("There are currently no songs in the queue.")

            embed = discord.Embed(title="Song Queue", description="", colour=discord.Color.green().dark_gold())
            i = 1
            for url in self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id]:
                embed.description += f"{i}) {url}\n"

                i += 1

            embed.set_footer(text="Thanks for using me!")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def adskip(self, ctx):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            commandd = "adskip"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            await ctx.send("skipping")
            ctx.voice_client.stop()
            await self.check_queue(ctx)


    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def skip(self, ctx):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            commandd = "skip"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            if ctx.voice_client is None:
                return await ctx.send("I am not playing any song.")

            if ctx.author.voice is None:
                return await ctx.send("You are not connected to any voice channel.")

            if ctx.author.voice.channel.id != ctx.voice_client.channel.id:
                return await ctx.send("I am not currently playing any songs for you.")

            poll = discord.Embed(title=f"Vote to Skip Song by - {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}", description="**80% of the voice channel must vote to skip for it to pass.**", colour=discord.Color.blue())
            poll.add_field(name="Skip", value=":white_check_mark:")
            poll.add_field(name="Stay", value=":no_entry_sign:")
            poll.set_footer(text="Voting ends in 15 seconds.")

            poll_msg = await ctx.send(embed=poll) # only returns temporary message, we need to get the cached message to get the reactions
            poll_id = poll_msg.id

            await poll_msg.add_reaction(u"\u2705") # yes
            await poll_msg.add_reaction(u"\U0001F6AB") # no

            await asyncio.sleep(15) # 15 seconds to vote

            poll_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(poll_id)

            votes = {u"\u2705": 0, u"\U0001F6AB": 0}
            reacted = []

            for reaction in poll_msg.reactions:
                if reaction.emoji in [u"\u2705", u"\U0001F6AB"]:
                    async for user in reaction.users():
                        if user.voice.channel.id == ctx.voice_client.channel.id and user.id not in reacted and not user.bot:
                            votes[reaction.emoji] += 1

                            reacted.append(user.id)

            skip = False

            if votes[u"\u2705"] > 0:
                if votes[u"\U0001F6AB"] == 0 or votes[u"\u2705"] / (votes[u"\u2705"] + votes[u"\U0001F6AB"]) > 0.79: # 80% or higher
                    skip = True
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="Skip Successful", description="***Voting to skip the current song was succesful, skipping now.***", colour=discord.Color.green())

            if not skip:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Skip Failed", description="*Voting to skip the current song has failed.*\n\n**Voting failed, the vote requires at least 80% of the members to skip.**", colour=discord.Color.red())

            embed.set_footer(text="Voting has ended.")

            await poll_msg.clear_reactions()
            await poll_msg.edit(embed=embed)

            if skip:
                ctx.voice_client.stop()
                await self.check_queue(ctx)




def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(music(bot))
```

-from head dev at rage bots

Comment: Thank you, but i got some error with queue 
queue_len = len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id])
KeyError: 415555016682635294

Comment: And also bot I stops playing song before song is ends

Comment: Just for note, I didn't use permissions and cooldowns